# Possible applications of the magnetic wormhole created in Barcelona

Tags: wormholes

Spanish scientists developed a magnetic wormhole (see https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/magnetic-wormhole-created-in-lab/ ) or at least that how it's described.

I'm not a physicist so I was wondering if some answers can give me an explanation on its meaning, main possible applications and if in more outlandish sci-fi setting can be use somehow (you know, teleportation, or so, I get that for space travel has no use tho, unless I'm wrong).

Comment: This is not a wormhole in space-time but a technique to get a kind of cloaking in the visible. The proposal is quite recent. You can find something to read at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking_device.

Comment: Sounds like something similar to the Romulan cloaking in Star Trek